# Use MySQL Stored Procedure to check for malicious code

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to write a stored procedure in MySql that will take a single parameter, and then check that parameter for any text that contains 'DROP','INSERT','UPDATE','TRUNCATE', etc., pretty much anything that isn't a SELECT statement. I know it's not ideal, but, unfortunately the SELECT statement is being built client-side, and to prevent some kind of man-in-the-middle change, it's just an added level of security from the server.

I've tried doing several means of accomplishing it, but, it's not working for me. I've come up with things similar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `myDatabase`.`execQuery` (in INC_query text)
BEGIN

#check to see if the incoming SQL query contains INSERT, DROP, TRUNCATE, 
#or UPDATE as an added measure of security
IF (
    SELECT LOCATE(LOWER(INC_query),'drop') OR
    SELECT LOCATE(LOWER(INC_query),'truncate') OR
    SELECT LOCATE(LOWER(INC_query),'insert') OR
    SELECT LOCATE(LOWER(INC_query),'update') OR
    SELECT LOCATE(LOWER(INC_query),'set')
    >= 1) 
THEN
    SET @command = INC_query;
    PREPARE statement FROM @command;
    EXECUTE statement;
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM database.otherTable; #just a generic output to know the procedure executed correctly, and will be removed later. Purely testing.

END IF;

END
```

Even if it contains any of my "filterable" words, it still executes the query. Any help would be appreciated, or if there's a better way of doing something, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you have a column called `updated_at` or `settings`? You can't possibly expect this to work as you intend. This kind of technique is the reason there's so many references to [clbuttic](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html) on the web.

You're really going to make a mess of things if you go down this road.

The only reasonable way to approach this is to send in the parameters for the kind of query you want to construct, then construct the query in your application using a vetted **white list** of allowed terms. An example expressed in JSON:

```
{
    "select" : {
      "table" : "users",
      "columns" : [ "id", "name", "DROP TABLE users", "SUM(date)", "password_hash" ],
      "joins" : {
         "orders" : [ "users.id", "orders.user_id" ]
      }
}
```

You just need to create a query constructor that emits this kind of thing, and another that converts it back into a valid query. You might want to list only particular columns for querying, as certain columns might be secret or internal only, not to be disclosed, like `password_hash` in this example.

You could also allow for patterns like `(SUM|MIN|MAX|AVG)\((\w+)\)` to capture specific grouping operations or `JOIN` conditions. It depends on how far you want to take this.

Comment: Oh I agree. Currently, this is a limited research project, so I'm not worried about columns being created that can match any of that criteria, but I see what you're saying. Use a query constructor to build out the columns for SELECT, FROM, and values for WHERE.

Comment: Unless you can parse SQL with 100% accuracy, which is going to be impossible, you should stick to a format you can parse and interpret easily. JSON is really easy to work with, the parser's already written, and emitting it from the browser is even easier. If you supervise the construction of your query, the chance of surprises is a lot lower, and any oversights are easy to correct. Plus, you can test it quite easily. Introducing subtle restrictions in your application, like not allowing columns with `set` in their name, is only going to make the system seem flaky and broken.

Comment: I understand. I appreciate the insight, and that reference to clbuttle is hilariously sad.